# iText 7 Adding barcode to every page with an event

Tags: barcode, itext7

I need to add a barcode to every page of the iText Pdf so I thought an event might be what I need but my following code puts the barcode only on the last page.

```
BarcodeEventHandler barCodeHandler = new  BarcodeEventHandler(pdfDoc, doc);
pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, barCodeHandler);

protected class BarcodeEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    protected PdfDocument Pdfdoc;
    protected Document doc;

    public BarcodeEventHandler(PdfDocument Pdfdoc, Document doc) {
        this.Pdfdoc = Pdfdoc;
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128(Pdfdoc);
        barcode.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
        barcode.setCode("12345678");
        barcode.setSize(12);
        Rectangle rect = barcode.getBarcodeSize();
        PdfFormXObject formXObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight() + 10));
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(formXObject, Pdfdoc);
        barcode.placeBarcode(pdfCanvas, ColorConstants.BLACK, ColorConstants.BLACK);
        Image bCodeImage = new Image(formXObject);
        bCodeImage.setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(90));        
        bCodeImage.setFixedPosition(100,200);       
        doc.add(bCodeImage);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way I can achive this. Thanks.

Ron

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about current page being flushed from `event` by casting it to `PdfDocumentEvent` since you are registering your event handler for a specific event type. Also, you don't need to pass `Document` to your handler at all. After getting `PdfPage` from the event you can easily add your barcode image to that page with `Canvas` helper class. Handler code:

```
protected class BarcodeEventHandler implements IEventHandler {
    protected PdfDocument Pdfdoc;

    public BarcodeEventHandler(PdfDocument Pdfdoc) {
        this.Pdfdoc = Pdfdoc;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        Barcode128 barcode = new Barcode128(Pdfdoc);
        barcode.setCodeType(Barcode128.CODE128);
        barcode.setCode("12345678");
        barcode.setSize(12);
        Rectangle rect = barcode.getBarcodeSize();
        PdfFormXObject formXObject = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight() + 10));
        PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(formXObject, Pdfdoc);
        barcode.placeBarcode(pdfCanvas, ColorConstants.BLACK, ColorConstants.BLACK);
        Image bCodeImage = new Image(formXObject);
        bCodeImage.setRotationAngle(Math.toRadians(90));
        bCodeImage.setFixedPosition(100,200);

        PdfPage page = ((PdfDocumentEvent)event).getPage();
        new Canvas(page, PageSize.A4.clone()).add(bCodeImage);
    }
}
```

Registering event handler (be sure to do so before adding content to the document):

```
BarcodeEventHandler barCodeHandler = new  BarcodeEventHandler(pdfDocument);
pdfDocument.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, barCodeHandler);
```

Comment: Alexey, I tried the same with EAN changing the first two lines for EAN instead of 128 but I got the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 21 out of bounds for length 10.  for the line barcode.placeBarCode                                      ;

Comment: Sorry it works fine for EAN as well just, needed the setcode to be 13 digits.